# Change input size multiple inputs, Bootstrap 5

Tags: bootstrap-5

I'm trying to change the size of inputs in a multiple-input row (Bootstrap 5). I can change the label size but not the two inputs next to it. I want one to be `col-7` and the other `col-1`. But the two inputs stay the same in size (see screenshot).

[image]

Here is the code:

```
<div class="row">
        <!-- left column -->
        <div class="col-5">

            <div class="input-group my-3">
                <label class="col-4 col-form-label"><?php echo $label['client-name']; ?>: *</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control col-7" name="clientname" value="<?php echo (isset($clientname)? $clientname : ""); ?>" />
                <input type="text" class="form-control col-1" name="clientID" value="<?php echo (isset($clientID)? $clientID : ""); ?>" />
            </div>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can use **width** for input text.use this code:

```
<div class="row">
<!-- left column -->
<div class="col-5">

    <div class="input-group my-3">
        <label class="col-form-label">
            clientname:
        </label>
        <div class="d-flex">
            <input type="text" class="form-control w-25" name="clientname"
            value="" />
        <input type="text" class="form-control " name="clientID"
            value="" style="width: 10%;" />
        </div>
      
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! This did the trick. I modified it slightly, though. I didn't remove the `col-4` size from the label as this destroys the layout, used `w-75` for the `clientname` input and `w-25` for `clientID`.

Answer (score 0):

You should put your label in a separated column giving it a width like I did here so that the label column always takes col-3 and the content column always takes col-9.

Then you can treat the content column as another row and split it in 7-2 (but the bootstrap canonic layout would expect 12 cols in total).

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  <div class="row">    
  
    <div class="col-3">
      <label class="col-4 col-form-label">Label</label>
    </div>
    
    <div class="col-9">
      <div class="row input-group">
        
        <div class="col-7">
          <input
            type="text"
            class="form-control"
            name="clientname" value="***" />
        </div>
        
        <div class="col-2">                    
          <input
            type="text"
            class="form-control"
            name="clientID"
            value="***" />      
        </div>
        
      </div>      
    </div>    
 </div>
```